# Parsing HTML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an xml which contains cdata section. I have managed to fetch the cdata text using XSLT.
But inside CDATA  we have html. So can anyone help me how can i parse the HTMl. Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="dummy">
            <xsl:value-of select="somexpath"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The ouptut till this is an html:

```
    <div class="feed-description">
<p style="text-align: justify;">Les amateurs du jeu Dance Central 3 pourront ajouter quelques nouvelles pièces à leur collection en février. Parmi les artistes qui seront disponibles via téléchargements, on retrouve le groupe de l'heure One Direction, Justin Bieber, Ellie Goulding et B.o.B. Dès demain le <strong>5 février</strong>, vous pourrez danser sur la chanson ''<strong>What Makes You Beautilful</strong>'' de One Direction.
</p>
</div>
```

Now i want to read the inner text of p tag using XSLT.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try

```
<xsl:variable name="dummy">
   <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set(somexpath)//p/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, none of them what you say you would like (sorry).  Those that occur to me off the bat (there are surely others) include:

1. You can create a workflow that extracts the HTML, passes it to Tidy or some similar tool to produce XHTML, reinserts it into the document as markup instead of as a character sequence, and then runs your stylesheet on the result.
2. You can write an HTML parser in XSLT, to take the character sequence in your input document and produce an element structure for it.  This will be tedious, error-prone, and time-consuming, and by the time you finish it the major browsers will have come out with new versions that handle corner cases differently, so your users will complain bitterly that your parser isn't doing it 'right'.  But if you like doing that sort of thing it will be challenging and enjoyable and when you succeed you will have serious hacker cred.
3. You can look for extensions to XSLT processors that can handle this task for you.  (I don't know of any off hand, but that doesn't mean they can't exist.)
4. You can re-think the design of your project.  You might for example restructure the input so that instead of HTML disguised as character data the content of whatever element is it is actual markup of the kind XSLT is designed to process.   You might move the processing of the HTML payload out of the XSLT and into Javascript and the DOM.  You might wash your hands of the whole problem and move to the South Seas.

Good luck.